# How to set Multiple return types with same status code in swagger swash buckle

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, swagger

I am working on swagger and I want to make multiple return types known to swagger from single function with same status code.

I have been using these tags on functions:

```
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(PagedResult<GetIncidentsReportResponse>))] 
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(IEnumerable<GetCountResponse>))]
```

Comment: please provide a code example from what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have been using these tags on functions [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(PagedResult<GetIncidentsReportResponse>))]
        [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(IEnumerable<GetCountResponse>))]